# I need to get the last two value after dot using javascript split

Tags: javascript

I am getting the results like demo.in,demo.co.in,demo.tv,demo.org.in
I need to split the extension separately using JavaScript split function

```
var vsp = i.split(".");
```

this is my code I will get the result as 
demo,in demo,co,in

but I need to get the extension separately

Comment: and if it is "foo.example.com"?

Comment: What are you calling "the extension"? Do you just want the part after the last period (.), or after the first period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/hZtxE/4/)**(demo version)

```
    var values = [
         "demo.in",
         "demo.co.in",
         "demo.tv","demo.org"
    ];
    var results = [];
    // iterate through the values
    for (var i = 0, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {

         // Split the parts on every dot.
         var parts = values[i].split(".");

         // Remove the first part (before the first dot).
         parts = parts.slice(1, parts.length);

         // Join the results together
         results.push(parts.join("."));
    };
    console.dir(results); // all done

    // Nicely display the values for the OP:
    for (var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += (i + 1) + ": " + results[i] + "<br />";
    };
```

Comment: why `\.`? Is it necessary?

Comment: @alex23—[split](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14) takes a *separator* that "may be a String of any length or it may be a RegExp object". There is no need to escape the "." if the value is a string, which it is in your answer.

Comment: @alex23—your answer does not use a regular expression, it's using a string.

Comment: If you want to use a regular expression (and there is no need to so), you'd use `values[i].split(/\./)`

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you want, so here's some functions to cover the likely cases:

```
var s = 'demo.co.in'

// Return everything before the first '.'
function getExtension(s) {
    var m = s.match(/^[^.]+/);
    return m? m[0] : '';
}

alert(getExtension(s)); // demo


// Return everything after the last '.'
function getExtension2(s) {
    var m = s.match(/[^.]+$/);
    return m? m[0] : '';
}

alert(getExtension2(s)); // in


// Return everything after the first '.'
function getExtension3(s) {
    return s.replace(/^[^.]+\./, '');
}

alert(getExtension3(s)); // co.in
```

Comment: me too have no idea about what he wants :)

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand exactly .. **"the extension"** . You can try like below code

```
var urls = "demo,demo.in,my.demo.co.in,demo.tv,demo.org.in"
          .split(',');

var splited = urls.reduce( function( o, n ){
   var parts = n.split( '.' );

   o[ n ] = (function(){
        var ext = [];
        while( !(parts.length == 1 || ext.length == 2) ) {
            ext.unshift( parts.pop() );    
        };
        return ext.join('.');
    }());

   return o;
}, {} );

console.log( JSON.stringify( splited ) );
```

which prints

```
{
    "demo":"",
    "demo.in":"in",
    "my.demo.co.in":"co.in",
    "demo.tv":"tv",
    "demo.org.in":"org.in"
}
```

process result using

```
for( var i in splited ) { 
     console.log( i, splited[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var vsp = i.split("."); 
for(var i=0; i< vsp.length; i++){
     if(i !== 0){ //leaving the first match 
         // do something with vsp[i]
     }
}
```

I hope you are not considering `www` also. :). If so, then keep `i>1` instead of `i !== 0`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it (probably none as easy as it should be). You could define a function like this:

```
function mySplit(str, delim) {
    var idx = (str.indexOf(delim) == -1) ? str.indexOf(delim) : str.length;
    return [str.substr(0,idx), str.substr(idx)];
}
```

And then call it like: `var sp = mySplit(i, ".");`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`lastIndexOf`](http://dochub.io/#javascript/string.lastindexof), which returns the location of the last `.` and from there you can get the rest of the string using [`substring`](http://dochub.io/#javascript/string.substring).

```
function getExtension(hostName) {
  var extension = null;

  if(hostName && hostName.length > 0 && hostName.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
    extension = hostName.substring(hostName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
  }

  return extension;
}
```

From there, you can use this function in a loop to get the extensions of many host names.

**Edit** Just noticed the "last two values" part in the title :) Thanks @rab

Comment: `getExtension( 'demo.org.in')` return `in`